# React Context for Array passing

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have the following app entry component:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const libraries: unknown[] = await sendRequest('/libraries');
        const softwareComponents: unknown[] = await sendRequest('/softwareComponents');

        localStorage.setItem('libraries', JSON.stringify(arraySetup(libraries, 'libraries')));
        localStorage.setItem('softwareComponents', JSON.stringify(arraySetup(softwareComponents, 'software-components')));
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    isAuthenticated() && fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I am fetching Arrays from two endpoints and then set the result in the Local Storage, so I can read from it in other components.

A child component is using the data like this:

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<any>>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const libraries = getLocalStorageItem('libraries');
    const softwareComponents = getLocalStorageItem('softwareComponents');
    const condition = libraries && softwareComponents;

    if (condition) {
      setData([...libraries, ...softwareComponents]);
    }
  }, []);

  const getDataLength = (category: string) => {
    return (data || []).filter((item: any) => item.category === category).length;
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <OwcGrid item xs={12} s={4}>

        <LibrariesCard numberOfElements={getDataLength('libraries')} /> // rendering here the length of the localStorage item.

      </OwcGrid>
```

**Goal/Challenge:**

I want to use `React.Context` to remove local storage implementation but I am not sure how to keep it as simple as possible.

I only saw guides which implemented dispatch actions and so on but this seems already too complex because I only fetch the data and don't change it as I only render it.

Are there any tipps or guides how to start with this?

Comment: You should not use localStorage for just sharing state. Instead use Context with useState or useReducer. Here is the article about how to do it from react docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible implementation with context:

```js
//context.tsx
import {
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useState,
} from 'react';

export interface LibsAndComponentsInterface {
  data: unknown[];
}

const LibsAndComponentsContext = createContext<
  LibsAndComponentsInterface | undefined
>(undefined);

// Wrap your App component with this
export function LibsAndComponentsProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  const [libs, setLibs] = useState<unknown[]>([]);
  const [components, setComponents] = useState<unknown[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const libraries: unknown[] = await sendRequest('/libraries');
        const softwareComponents: unknown[] = await sendRequest(
          '/softwareComponents'
        );

        setLibs(libraries);
        setComponents(softwareComponents);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    isAuthenticated() && fetchData();
  }, []);

  const ctxValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      data: [...libs, ...components],
    }),
    [libs, components]
  );

  return (
    <LibsAndComponentsContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
      {children}
    </LibsAndComponentsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useLibsAndComponents() {
  const ctx = useContext(LibsAndComponentsContext);

  if (ctx == null) {
    throw new Error(
      'useLibsAndComponents must be inside LibsAndComponentsProvider'
    );
  }

  return ctx;
}
```

```js
// later in your components

 const { data } = useLibsAndComponents()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete setup for React Context. Please use typescript if needed.

**MyContextProvider.js**

```
const { createContext, useState } = require("react");

//Create a context
export const Mycontext = createContext();

//Created a component that helps to provide the context.
const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  //Declare all the states that you need
  const [libraries, setLibraries] = useState([]);
  const [softwareComponents, setSoftwareComponents] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Mycontext.Provider
      //provide all the state, function as value that you need in any child component 
      value={{
        libraries,
        setLibraries,
        softwareComponents,
        setSoftwareComponents
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Mycontext.Provider>
  );
};
export default MyContextProvider;
```

**index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import MyContextProvider from "./MyContextProvider";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
//Wrap App component By the MycontextProvider component
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <MyContextProvider>
      <App />
    </MyContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./Child";
import { Mycontext } from "./MyContextProvider";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
  //This is the way of getting value from context here useContext is the builtin hook and Mycontext is the context name
  const { setLibraries, setSoftwareComponents } = useContext(Mycontext);
  //After getting data from API use setLibraries and setSoftwareComponents to store data in the state(context) instead of local storage.
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Mycontext } from "./MyContextProvider";

const ChildComponent = () => {

  const { libraries, softwareComponents } = useContext(Mycontext);
  //Here is your state you can use it as your need.
  console.log(libraries, softwareComponents);
  
  return <h1>Child Component</h1>;
};
export default ChildComponent;
```